# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) error with Firebase Storage

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm using a download URL to get an HTML file from my Firebase Storage and display it in a template. In my template I'm using `<img>` with the `src` set to the download URL. The browser shows a broken file and the console says

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com/o/English_Videos%2FWalker_Climbs_a_Tree%2Fscript.html?alt=media&token=8772258d-9417-4f93-b16d-29d353c5262
```

and then the download URL. The download URL works when I put it in a browser window. As the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) suggested I made this file

```js
[
  {
    "origin": "*",
    "method": "GET",
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

named it `cors.json`, and ran

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com
```

I updated `gsutil`. I cleared my Chrome cache. I tried my app in Chromium. I tried `POST` instead of `GET`. I'm still getting the CORB error. What else should I try? Do I need to set `Content-Type`?

Comment: *“I'm using a download URL to get an HTML file from my Firebase Storage and display it in a template. In my template I'm using `<img>` with the src set to the download URL.”* — Given that, it sounds like the browser is blocking your frontend code from accessing the response because you’re trying to use a text/html response in a context where the browser instead expects an image. Regardless, based on the error message cited in the question, you have a CORB problem, not a CORS problem. So your CORS configuration isn’t going to have any effect either way on this.

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/441757/sideshowbarker, when I get rid of the <img> tag the CORB error message goes away. Now my page displays the download URL. How do I convert the download URL into the HTML file?

Comment: I'm using $http.get(downloadURL). It's almost working, my template is displaying the file, but the HTML tags are showing as well...

Answer (score 0):

sideshowbarker was right, the problem was I was using `<img>` to display an HTML text file. When I got rid of the `<img>` tag the CORB error went away. Instead I used `$http.get(downloadURL)` to get the file, then `$sce.trustAsHtml(doc.data);` to sanitize the HTML, then in the AngularJS template I used `<div ng-bind-html="myFile"></div>` to display it in the template. Here's the AngularJS controller code:

```js
firebase.firestore().collection('Videos').doc($scope.longLanguage).collection($scope.longLanguage + '_Videos').doc($scope.movieTitle).collection('Clips').doc($scope.movieTitle + '_999999').get()
  .then(function(doc) {
    $http.get(doc.data().lyricsDownloadURL)
    .then(function(doc) {
      $scope.lyrics = $sce.trustAsHtml(doc.data);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

and here's the AngularJS template:

```js
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <div ng-bind-html="lyrics"></div>
</div>
```